# Meter una variable string como hash en otra variable string

Tags: ruby

Tengo una variable string

```
nombre = ‘juan’
```

Y  la quiero meter como hash en otra variable

```
Todos = ( { "nombre" => ‘juan’ })
```

**“la linea de arriba es lo que quiero saber como se hace”**

Y cada vez que la variable nombre cambie, por ejemplo

```
nombre = ‘pedro’
```

Quiero agregar estos datos como hash en esa otra variable
Y que quede como un hash

```
Todos = ( { "nombre" => ‘juan’,  "nombre" => ‘pedro’ })
```

**“la linea de arriba es lo que quiero saber como se hace”**

De antemano muchas gracias por su pronta respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para crear un *hash* (en tu primer ejemplo) solo quita los paréntesis y pon el nombre `juan` entre comillas (para indicar que es un *string*); por ejemplo:

```
todos = { "nombre" => "juan" }
```

Alternativamente (y uso más común en *Ruby*) podrías utilizar un símbolo en lugar de un *string* como llave del *hash*:

```
todos = { nombre: "juan" }
```

En tu segundo caso lo que necesitas es un **arreglo** donde cada elemento sea un *hash*; por ejemplo:

```
todos = [{ nombre: "juan" }, { nombre: "pedro" }]
```

En este ejemplo debes utilizar un arreglo ya que un *hash* no puede tener llaves duplicadas (e.g. `nombre`).

Para agregar un nombre más a la lista, simplemente harías lo siguiente:

```
todos << { nombre: "carlos" }
```

Comment: Todo bien amigo @Gerry, pero al poner el simbolo << se genera el siguiente error: undefined method `<<' for

Comment: @rrg1459 Ese método funciona sobre arreglos, es decir, como el ejemplo 2. Si quisieras iniciar solo con un nombre y después agregar solo cambia agrega los corchetes al primer ejemplo; así: `todos = [{ nombre: "juan" }]` y sobre ese puedes ya llamar el método `<<`.